# Is this considered "web scraping"? Is it "legal"?

Tags: curl, web-scraping

I've made tools to do the following:

- 1) Download Instagram HTML page of some user via cURL
- 2) Process downloaded HTML page and find all images in the format:

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx_x.jpg

And construct a list of the images

- 3) Download them one by one from Instagram's CDN

Is this web scraping? Does Instagram "hate" that I do this? Can someone take legal action against me? Is making POST request to Instagram to obtain info illegal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Instagram's terms of service rather than programming.

Comment: "Is making POST request to Instagram to obtain info illegal?" Of course not. POST requests are not illegal. Improper usage of Instagram as prohibited by their terms of service, on the other hand, may be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it solicits legal advice rather than programming advice.

Answer (score 2):

From Instagram's TOS:

> 10) We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with Instagram's express consent).