# Can't get data from inside of span-tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** Instagram page, and want to get/access div-tags present inside of span-tag. but I can't! the HTML of the Instagram page looks like as

```
 <head>--</head>
    <body>
       <span id="react-root" aria-hidden="false">
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" role="presentation">…</form>
       <section class="_9eogI E3X2T">
          <main class="SCxLW  o64aR" role="main">
             <div class="v9tJq VfzDr">
                 <header class=" HVbuG">…</header>
                 <div class="_4bSq7">…</div>
                 <div class="fx7hk">…</div>
             </div>
          </main>
      </section>
    </body>
```

I do, it as

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib2
html_page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.instagram.com/cherrified_/?hl=en")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"lxml")
span_tag = soup.find('span') # return span-tag correctly
span_tag.find_all('div')    # return empty list, why ?
```

please also specify an example.

Comment: Please provide a small example that others can run and reproduce your error.

Comment: done sir, now u can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram is a Single Page Application powered by React, which means its source is just a simple "empty" page that loads JavaScript to dynamically generate the content in the browser after downloading.

Click "View source" or go to `view-source:https://www.instagram.com/cherrified_/?hl=en` in Chrome. This is the HTML you download with `urllib.request`.

You can see that there is a single `<span>` tag, which does not include a `<div>` tag. (Note: `<div>` inside a `<span>` [is not allowed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)).

Scraping instagram.com this way is not possible. [It also might not be legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424584/is-this-considered-web-scraping-is-it-legal) (I am not a lawyer).

Notes:

- your HTML code example doesn't include a closing tag for `<span>`.
- your HTML code example doesn't match the link you provide in the python snippet.
- in the last line of the python snippet you probably meant `span_tag.find_all('div')` (note the variable name and the singular `'div'`).